# Recursive method to generate all partitions of a String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve this problem with the `partitioning` of a `String`. Let's take "abc" for example.
There are 4 `partitions` - `{a,bc}, {ab,c}, {abc}, {a,b,c}.`
I am trying to write a `recursive` method to generate the `partitions` to an `ArrayList` of `Lists` but I struggle to do so. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
static List<List<String>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
static List<String> partition = new ArrayList<>();

static void recurse(int size, String str) {
    if (str.length() <= size) {
        return;
    }
    partition.add(str.substring(0, size));
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (size < str.length())
            recurse(i, str.substring(size));
    }
    partitions.add(partition);
}
```

Now when i call this method it outputs

```
[[, a, b, ab], [, a, b, ab], [, a, b, ab], [, a, b, ab]]
```

instead of `[[a, b, c], [a, bc], [ab, c], [abc]]`

, so i must be doing something wrong:

```
recurse(0, "abc");
    System.out.println(partitions.toString());
```

Comment: You are passing in a size of 3 and a string of length 3. The first check in the recurse method says to return if they are equal

Comment: You are correct i fixed it but the output still isnt right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using global variable isn't a good idea.

A recursive function may return List of partitions.

So, think with function's input and output

**Example:**

> "ABC"

`func("ABC") => func("BC") => func("C")`

`func("C") returns [["C"]]`

So you can append **"B"** in front of **"C"** or create a partition.

`func("BC") returns [["BC"], ["B", "C"]]`

And then do above thing again with **"A"**

`func("ABC") returns [["ABC"], ["A", "BC"], ["AB", "C"], ["ABC"]]`

**CODE:**

```
static List<List<String>> recursive(String str) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (str.length() == 1) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());
        result.get(0).add(str);
        return result;
    }

    for (List<String> list : recursive(str.substring(1))) {
        List<String> append = new ArrayList<>(list);
        append.set(0, str.substring(0, 1) + append.get(0));
        List<String> add = new ArrayList<>(list);
        add.add(0, str.substring(0, 1));
        result.add(append);
        result.add(add);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**ADD:**

Also, your code creates `partition` just once. So `partition`s in `partitions` is from same reference!

Because of it, add or edit a `partition` affects every `partition`s.

So, as you see, all `partition`s are same.

Because of these reasons, you'd better create new `ArrayList` each step, not use global variable.

Comment: That was my thought process too but recursion that return objects is very confusing to me

Comment: The code looks corrrect. @ikicha, one minor correction on : result.add(new ArrayList<>()); it has to be result.add(new ArrayList<String>()); Otherwise it will complain during compilation

Comment: @Yohannes yes, you're right. But I know recent version of java compiler(maybe 7+) can guess the generic type by type inference because i declare `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: @ikicha, You'r right I think I heard that, May be In java 8. For unknown reason my java 7 compiler could not guess the type from the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, if you'd prefer to use Java 8 streams rather than traditional iteration:

```
private Stream<List<String>> partitions(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty())
        return Stream.of(new ArrayList<>());
    else
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, text.length()).boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> partitions(text.substring(i))
                .peek(p -> p.add(0, text.substring(0, i))));
}
```

For example, `partitions("abcde").forEach(System.out::println)` will print all partitions of the string.

If you want to convert back to a list, then:

```
List<List<String>> partitions = partitions(text).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you're not familiar with streams, the `else` clause can be interpreted as: for all numbers between 1 and the length of the string (inclusive), stream all partitions of the substring for that number onwards and then insert the substring to that number at the start of each item.